# Notepad ++: how to remove all text before and after a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to just keep the code for each line in this text, what is the regular expression for this

```
 {"name": "Canada", "countryCd": "CA", "code": 393},
 {"name": "Syria", "countryCd": "SR", "code": 3535},
 {"name": "Germany", "countryCd": "GR", "code": 3213}
```

The expected result would be

```
CA
SR
GR
```

Comment: Use a JSON parser or write your own.

Comment: Sounds simple, a regex to look for two capital letters between double quotes.  So what have you tried so far?  We can help you get it working.

Comment: What would be the regular expression for matching two capitals

Comment: I take it then that you haven't researched this at all.

Comment: [A-Z]{2}  would find 2 capital letters together.  Then add your global or multi line flags if needed /gm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a hack (see @Totos comment) but works for your requirements:

```
.*"([A-Z]{2})".*
```

This needs to be replaced by `$1`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/4ebs9R/1/) (side node: isn't Germany usually `GER` ?)

Comment: I just placed dummy examples.

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ I would do a find and replace like:

```
.*?"countryCd": "([^"]+)".*
```

And replace that with:

```
\1
```

That way if for some reason your country code was not just 2 letters it would be captured correctly.  The [^"] is a negative character class, meaning anything that isn't " and the + makes it at least 1 character.  I find using negative character classes does what is actually intended.

And in this case you want to capture whatever is in the quotes after the country CD, and this will do the trick.